# Traefik+Docker Reverse Proxy - Different Auth For Different Paths?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm running a Docker service (OwnTracks Recorder), using Traefik as a reverse proxy for authentication.  It's setup is via docker-compose; here are the labels on the service:

```
  labels:
    - traefik.enable=true
    - traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/owntracks
    - traefik.frontend.auth.basic=user1:hash1,user2:hash2
```

This works as intended.  The problem I'm trying to solve is that Owntracks actually has two elements: a dashboard, which would be at https://example.com/owntracks, and an api, at https://example.com/owntracks/pub.  Although owntracks itself has no built-in authentication, I'd like to limit the dashboard to only user1, while allowing all authenticated users to reach the api. Owntrack's [documentation](https://github.com/owntracks/recorder#nginx) uses ngnix as an example, which I think in my case might look something like:

```
location /owntracks/dashboard/ {
     auth_basic              ....;
     proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8083/;
     proxy_http_version      1.1;
     proxy_set_header        Host $host;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
location /owntracks/pub/ {
     auth_basic              ....;
     proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8083/pub/;
     proxy_http_version      1.1;
     proxy_set_header        Host $host;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

The problem is, I can't figure out how to configure something like this in Traefik.  As I understand it, you get one traefik.frontend.auth.basic "label" for this whole container?  Ideally, I'd prefer to set this up via labels in Owntracks' docker-compose file, to avoid the need for custom per-service config in Traefik itself (i.e. so I could rely on Traefik's automatic discovery of the service).

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use segments.  Traefik's [documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers-with-multiple-ports-segment-labels) is a bit misleading:

> Segment labels are used to define routes to a container exposing multiple ports. A segment is a group of labels that apply to a port exposed by a container. You can define as many segments as ports exposed in a container.

Actually, segments can be used not only for the purpose of containers using multiple ports, and you can define more segments than there are ports exposed on the container.  In this case, it was as simple as:

```
  labels:
    - traefik.enable=true

    - traefik.segment1.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/owntracks/pub;ReplacePath:/pub
    - traefik.segment1.frontend.auth.basic=user1:hash1,user2:hash2

    - traefik.segment2.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/owntracks
    - traefik.segment2.frontend.auth.basic=user1:hash1
```